# Is there a better approach for personality detection from twitter data?

Tags: nlp, prediction

I have tried different approaches like multinomialNB, SVM, MLPClassifier, CNN as well as LSTM network to train the dataset that consists of tweets and labels (big 5 classes - openness, conscientiousness, extraversion, agreeable, neuroticism). But the accuracy is at around 60% even after using word2vec, NRC features & MRC features. Is there something that I can do to improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please add few more details about the dataset you are using?

For example I would add:

- Dataset size (number of samples)
- Classes distribution (are they balanced or not)
- Do you do any preprocessing?

Without the above information I would just guess but if I were you would try:

- clean the tweets from noise e.g usernames,garbage symbols etc.
- If the dataset is small

  - try random search on models (Naive Bayes ,SVM, Logistic regression) using various vectorizations strategies e.g bag of words, tf-idf and do hyper-parameter search
  - try applying transfer learning from a model trained on tweets, for example for sentiment analysis.
- If the dataset is large enough

  - try neural network approach

    - Embedding(Glove, word2vec, fasttext) + RNN(LSTM, GRU) + [Attention](https://medium.com/datalogue/attention-in-keras-1892773a4f22)

      - try training own embedding
      - use pretrained ones such as [those](https://github.com/loretoparisi/word2vec-twitter)
    - Embedding + CNN + RNN
    - Bag of words + FNN
- If classes are not balanced

  - use weighted loss
  - try to balance them
- try stacking multiple models ([ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning))

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is the main premise of your project to do personality detection? If  not, I would recommend using the Google Sentiment API to calculate sentiment of Twitter data.

Comment: Yes it is. And I dont think google sentiment API will help